# How can I add Post https request in bzm-Parallel controller

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

How can I add Post https request in bzm-Parallel controller.

I want to add/combine 4 https Post requests which uploads 4 files at a time using bzm-parallel controller.

I tried simply putting normal post/upload request in 'bzm-parallel controller' but it didn't workout.
also the provided csv data configuration is not working if I use bzm-parallel Controller getting file not found exception.
${path} Variable provided in CSV not picking while execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) works per se it should work under the Parallel Controller as well. Double check that you can perform the upload using single thread and inspect request and response details using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. Once request will be successful - put it under the Parallel Controller.

---

Be aware that Parallel Controller was developed primarily to overcome JMeter's limitation with regards to impossibility to kick off extra threads to mimic i.e. [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) requests. It is not the best option for your use case, I would recommend consider using [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) instead.